# How to add a css style from a file to a link <a>

Tags: html, css

I have a link in which I wish to have it with a specific css.

The css file is called: **my_django.css** and it has this [snap] data:

```
.selectize-control.multi .selectize-input.disabled [data-value] 
.remove {
 background: none;
}


.selectize-control.multi .selectize-input [data-value] {
 -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
 -moz-border-radius: 2px;
 border-radius: 2px;
 border: none;
 background-color: #ff5067;
 padding: 5px 7px;
}
```

My goal is to access the file above and have it 'styled' on a  specific url with `.selectize-control.multi .selectize-input [data-value] {`.

at the moment, I do it *manually* where I embed the style in the  tag. So it looks like this:

```
    {% for tag in old_post.tags.all %}              
        <a style="webkit-border-radius: 2px; moz-border-radius: 2px;  border-radius: 2px;  border: none;  background-color: #ff5067;  padding: 5px 7px; color: white;" href="{% url 'by_mylabel' tag.name %} "> {{ tag.name }}</a>                  
    {% endfor %}
```

Obviously I don't want to copy past it to every location I have and merly wish to utilize the file with the ID. Wonder how to do it. I'm not a CSS/HTML expert. When I use DIV tag, the result comes in a new line (not good) so I take it that it must be inside `<a` but not sure how.

**What have I tried:**

```
<link href="{% static "css/my_django.css" %}" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet"/>

        {% for tag in old_post.tags.all %}              
            <a class="selectize-control multi" href="{% url 'by_mylabel' tag.name %} "> {{ tag.name }}</a>                  
        {% endfor %}
```

however the result comes empty. (The file is there and works elsewhere!)

**edit 2:**
ok - what worked and suggested by @connexo is to place the entire code in a different file. So what I did was:

```
.class {

webkit-border-radius: 2px; 
moz-border-radius: 2px;  
border-radius: 2px;  
border: none;  
background-color: #f90223;  
padding: 5px 7px; 
color: white;
}
```

the key was the .class and the html would be the same:

```
<a class="class" href="{% url 'by_mylabel' tag.name %} "> {{ tag.name }}</a>
```

Comment: Give your links a CSS class, and put the definitions you currently have inline in that CSS class instead. It doesn't get any more basic when it comes to CSS. This is what you learn in lesson one on day one of a CSS course.

Comment: @connexo yes, I tried that.but somehow the result I get are empty. Not sure what I'm doing incorrectly.

Comment: If you don't show what you've tried, how is anyone supposed to help? You want us to guess?

Comment: @connexo fair enough. I've revised the post.

Comment: Read comment #1 again, do that, and come back if it fails.

Comment: @connexo :-) thanks! apparently I had to take a different direction and add new file with the copy-paste of the required block. [see edit2]

Answer (score 0):

To apply this style you have to load the CSS by adding it to the `<head>` section of your layout, eg:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/your.css">
  <!-- ... other stuff in head ... -->      
</head>
```

and then apply the specified class to your link

```
   {% for tag in old_post.tags.all %}              
        <a class="selectize-control multi" href="{% url 'by_mylabel' tag.name %} "> {{ tag.name }}</a>                  
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score -1):

i dont know why css selectors is not a choice. Add classes or Ids to your a tag. Also, create css file for shared styles and import it from your html document.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Well, im exposing at least ome valid solution, maybe more.

Regards